# Devices Display Settings (ie Android Screen Zoom & Font)

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I have been tasked to complete an Andoid app alongside our existing IOS app.
The project skeleton for Android is already there I just need to fill in the gaps to bring it up to speed with the IOS version.

I have been testing via my own phone and have been struggling with fonts being too large on my Galaxy S6.
Now I have just realised that this is due to the actual Zomm and Font display settings on my device (my eyesite isn't the best).

My question is, is it possible to retrieve these zoom settings from my device so that I can adjust font's etc accordingly?

Pretty new to Xamarin but I'm getting there - hopefully you'll have some pointers to help me get further.

Answer (score 3):

As we all know, the conversion formula from dp and px: px = dp * density

It can be seen that if the design width is 360dp, we can only modify the value of density if we want to ensure that the px values calculated by all devices are exactly the width of the screen.

By reading the source code and [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), we can see that the density is a member variable in **DisplayMetrics**, and the **DisplayMetrics** instance is available through **Resources#getDisplayMetrics**, and the **Resouces** is obtained through the Activity or Application Context.

We can familiarize ourselves with the following variables related to DisplayMetrics neutralization adaptation:

- **DisplayMetrics#density** is the above density
- **DisplayMetrics#densityDpi** is the above dpi
- **DisplayMetrics#scaledDensity** The scaling factor of the font, which is
  equal to the density under normal conditions, but will change this
  value after adjusting the system font size.

**Solution:**

The following assumes that the design map width is 360dp and is adapted to the wide dimension.

Then the adapted density = device real width (unit px) / 360, then we only need to modify our calculated density in the system, the code is implemented as follows:

```
private static void setCustomDensity( Activity activity,Application application)
 {
    DisplayMetrics appDisplaymetrics = application.Resources.DisplayMetrics;
    float targetDensity = appDisplaymetrics.WidthPixels / 360;
    int targetDensityDpi = (int)(160 * targetDensity);

    appDisplaymetrics.Density = appDisplaymetrics.ScaledDensity = targetDensity;
    appDisplaymetrics.DensityDpi = (Android.Util.DisplayMetricsDensity)targetDensityDpi;

    DisplayMetrics activityDisplayMetrics = activity.Resources.DisplayMetrics;
    activityDisplayMetrics.Density = activityDisplayMetrics.ScaledDensity = targetDensity;
    activityDisplayMetrics.DensityDpi = (Android.Util.DisplayMetricsDensity)targetDensityDpi;
}
```

Also called in the **Activity#onCreate** method. The code is relatively simple, and does not involve the call of the system non-public api, so theoretically it will not affect the stability of the app.

**Note:** If you switch fonts in the system settings and then return to the app, the fonts have not changed. So you have to listen to the font switch, call **Application#registerComponentCallbacks** to register the `onConfigurationChanged` listener.

Comment: Very helpful. One correction: the 360 should be 360.0F . A value of 1024 for example yields a targetDensity of 0, because that line delivers an integer result on android which is then re-cast to float

Comment: @Frank Yeah, thanks for sharing a correction.