# How to dynamically and automatically set FontSize based on view.Width?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, fonts, runtime, font-size

"TRYING OUT AUTO SIZING"
[image: img_1]
Font size too large, so much so part of the string is cut off (when text is too large, a portion is cut off and replaced with ellipsis).

"test text"
[image: img_2]
Font size too small. The fontSize is a third of its respective view (estimating).

How to set the fontSize of an Element to the size of the Element (and or containing Views) width? Use the examples above as reference - "test text" would take up much more of the view and "TRYING OUT AUTO SIZING" would take up far less.

NOTE: Black boxes denote other elements.

The desired goal is an element (label and or containing view) that when text is changed at run-time, the fontSize is set according to the text assigned and width available to it (this remains constant after build). So that all text is viewable in the string and it uses the width available to it.

Purpose is to support multiple platforms on a variety of devices with widely different scaling.

Whats been tried? NamedSizes based on the idiom (phone/tablet/etc) and manipulating these with multiplication and division based on OS (platform, i.e., IOS, Android, etC). This can't be best practice and there must be a way to go about accomplish this.

Following Xamarin.Forms guide for "fitting text to available size" or "empirically fitting text" yields results that are not as expected.. ["CH5: Dealing with sizes"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05#empirically-fitting-text)

Please advise on best practice and/or next steps.

Struct

```
struct FontCalc
{
    public FontCalc(Label label, double fontSize, double containerWidth)
        : this()
    {
        // Save the font size.
        FontSize = fontSize;

        // Recalculate the Label height.
        label.FontSize = fontSize;
        SizeRequest sizeRequest =
            label.Measure(containerWidth, Double.PositiveInfinity);

        // Save that height.
        TextHeight = sizeRequest.Request.Height;
    }

    public double FontSize { private set; get; }

    public double TextHeight { private set; get; }
}
```

Implementation

Label label;

```
public EmpiricalFontSizePage()
{
    label = new Label();

    Padding = new Thickness(0, Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS ? 30 : 0, 0, 0);
    ContentView contentView = new ContentView
    {
        Content = label
    };
    contentView.SizeChanged += OnContentViewSizeChanged;
    Content = contentView;
}

void OnContentViewSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // Get View whose size is changing.
    View view = (View)sender;

    if (view.Width <= 0 || view.Height <= 0)
        return;

    label.Text =
        "This is text displayed. Does it work?";

    // Calculate the height of the rendered text.
    FontCalc lowerFontCalc = new FontCalc(label, 10, view.Width);
    FontCalc upperFontCalc = new FontCalc(label, 100, view.Width);

    while (upperFontCalc.FontSize - lowerFontCalc.FontSize > 1)
    {
        // Get the average font size of the upper and lower bounds.
        double fontSize = (lowerFontCalc.FontSize + upperFontCalc.FontSize) / 2;

        // Check the new text height against the container height.
        FontCalc newFontCalc = new FontCalc(label, fontSize, view.Width);

        if (newFontCalc.TextHeight > view.Height)
        {
            upperFontCalc = newFontCalc;
        }
        else
        {
            lowerFontCalc = newFontCalc;
        }
    }

    // Set the final font size and the text with the embedded value.
    label.FontSize = lowerFontCalc.FontSize;
    label.Text = label.Text.Replace("??", label.FontSize.ToString("F0"));
}
```

(implementation code from XF docs linked above)

Comment: Regarding the adaptation of fonts, it is first necessary to distinguish between devices of different systems. If it is an Android device, you can modify the system's density to display on different Android devices. If it is an iOS device, it can be displayed according to the different screen sizes of iOS. After all, the device size of iOS is not as diverse as Android, which is quite feasible.

Comment: Okey,In android , you can modify density to display on different android devices.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302016/devices-display-settings-ie-android-screen-zoom-font This need to do in native platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use the NuGet package: [Forms9Patch](https://baskren.github.io/Forms9Patch/guides/Label.html)

Using its `Lines` and `AutoFit` properties we can achieve our desired result. In our case, we want one line and we want our `FontSize` set to what is required to make our text fit within one line. `Lines = 1`, `AutoFit = Forms9Patch.AutoFit.Width`, and `FontSize` set to a large value (does not matter if it is well over our desired max as setting `AutoFit` to `Width` shrinks font till to what is required to make text fit within our specified number of lines) results in a `Label` that automatically adjusts its `FontSize` to the maximum space available to it given the text length.